# C# HttpClient post API with different header and raw body

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient

I am calling a POST API using C#. For which I am using HttpClient. I need to pass following from headers.

```
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:hshshkdoFFHDLjljH56JDKJKJLDgsd4545fjoud==
source:dataweb
Connection-from:downtown-ps
Token:545187845515154545ddiujkjdkjdjidjkdkjdkjdkjkdjkjdkjkdj
```

FYI: I have changed the above values due to confidentiality.

From body I need to pass a string as a RAW data.

I don't know how can I achieve this. Please help.

Comment: So set the headers accordingly, and use [a `StringContent` instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent) for the body. What's the question?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0)? And especially about [setting headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpclient-defaultrequestheaders)?

Comment: @Xerillio yes I read the documentation but could not figure out how to write all of the headers

Comment: @Xerillio I have token and authorization in headers, that's where I got stuck.

Comment: Your Authorization header is either wrong or non-standard.  It should have 2 components, a scheme and a parameter.  For example, basic auth contains "Basic <credentials>" where credentials is a base64 encoded user:password.

Comment: @Neil I know, I have changed it for security purpose

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Please show us what you've done so far. Did you try `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme, token)`?